# How does one queue a task to a module in google appengine in the Python runtime

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the google appengine push queue to queue a request to a worker module:

```
taskqueue.add( queue_name='workerqueue', 
 url='http://worker.<my-app>.appspot.com/uploadworker', 
 params={'imagenumber':str(imagenumber),   
         'user_id':user_id} )
```

but I get the error "relative URL may not have a scheme or location". Does this mean that it is not possible to address modules from queued tasks?

Comment: Problem solved. I was running two versions and using different queue names

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a target when using the task queue using the `target` parameter: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#Task